# How can I proportionally resize a DataGridView when a form resizes?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a`DataGridView` whose `Dock` property is set to `Fill`. When I resize my form the `DataGridView` will resize. In my case, I set `DataGridView` column width with a fixed value. Like so:

```
dgGrid.Columns[0].Width = 50;
dgGrid.Columns[1].Width = 126;
dgGrid.Columns[2].Width = 100;
```

I am trying to get the columns in my `DataGridView` to resize proportionally when the control is resized. How can I do it programmatically when my grid column with is set like the above?

Comment: You seem to manage to use capital letters when writing code. Why not when writing English?

Comment: Setting the width in percentage would be the solution. To bad WinForms don't support this. Considering switching to WPF instead of the now obsolete WinForms.

Comment: @Claus: I'm not sure why "switch to WPF" has become the answer whenever someone doesn't know how to implement something in WPF. Switching to WPF is certainly not a miracle cure. In particular, where do you find a DataGridView control for a WPF application without embedding the WinForms one?

Comment: <DataGrid /> (that was hard, huh :p)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no particularly elegant way of doing this when you hard-code the column width values. I'm not sure why you have to do that in the first place; the question doesn't give much background information.

The better solution is to call the [`AutoResizeColumns` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158594.aspx), which will automatically adjust the width of all your columns using the specified size mode. You would call this method in the handler for your form's `Resize` event. For example:

```
protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
{
    myDataGridView.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
}
```

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b2wakt.aspx) gives more information about sizing options for the `DataGridView` control.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DataGridView.Resize event to canlculate new width for every column depending on new size of

Answer (score 0):

```
datagridview.Columns["columnName"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
```

Comment: Note that setting this property will prevent the user from resizing columns manually using the mouse.